# Why is Windows removing the quotes ("") from the target destination of my shortcut?

Tags: windows-7

I want to run a game in windowed mode. I know that it works for this particular game. So I made a shortcut for the game.exe and opened properties, selected "Target", and typed:

> "D:\Programs\Sims2\mansion\TSBin\Sims2EP9.exe" -w

However, after I click OK the computer is mysteriously removing the quotes. I can check this by re-opening and seeing that the quotes have disappeared. This is causing the windowed mode to not work.

Is there a way I can fix this?

Answer (score 5):

The quotes are not necessary because there is no withspace between path names, so windows automatically removes the quotes around the file names ... They are not necessary ...

I don't think that your game doesn't start up in windowed mode because of the missing quotes ... Should be another reason ...